# ghci not creating new lines (outputs are on the same line too)

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have just got Haskell installed using GHCup in WSL2 (Ubuntu). However, there is a problem with the `ghci` interpreter.

When I start `ghci` and I press enter, the interpreter doesn't create a new line, but rather prints in the console the prefix `ghci` and get ready to receive the next command.

A new line is only after I enter a new command and get the output in the same line.

Below is an example of what I see in the terminal.

```bash
$ ghci
GHCi, version 9.2.8: [https://www.haskell.org/ghc/](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/)  :? for help
ghci> ghci> ghci> ghci> ghci> 4+48
ghci>
```

And below is what I would expect:

```bash
$ ghci
GHCi, version 9.2.8: [https://www.haskell.org/ghc/](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/)  :? for help
ghci>
ghci>
ghci>
ghci>
ghci> 4 + 4
8
ghci>
```

Just to make it clear: i don't have problems with haskell scripts, but with the `ghci`.

I tried to run `ghci` from other terminals as well. When starting `wsl` from Powershell or the normal windows terminal and then `ghci`, the issue was still there.

Comment: Do other programs work? What happens if you just `cat > test.txt` and try typing into it?

Comment: Other programs work. `cat > test.txt` works.